# nSubstitute mocking exception

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mocking

Here is my BLL Service which work with counties:

```
public class CountryBLLService : ICountryBLL
{
    private readonly ITimeSheetContext _context;

    public CountryBLLService(ITimeSheetContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public void CreateCountry(Country country)
    {
        _context.Countries.Create(country);
    }

    public Country GetCountry(Guid id)
    {
        return _context.Countries.Read(id);
    }

    public bool RemoveCountry(Guid id)
    {
        return _context.Countries.Delet(id);
    }

    public void UpdateCountry(Country country)
    {
        _context.Countries.Update(country);
    }
}
```

And here is a TimeSheetContext:

```
 public class TimeSeetContext : ITimeSheetContext
{
    public ICountryRepository Countries { get; private set; }


    public TimeSeetContext()
    {
        Countries = new CountryRepository();
    }
}
```

So, i want to UnitTest throwException CountryBLL service using mock TimeSheetContext. But im getting error: NSubstitute extension methods like .Received() can only be called on objects created using Substitute.For() and related methods.

Here is my sad try:

```
[TestClass]
public class CountryTestBLL
{
    ICountryBLL countrybLL;
    ITimeSheetContext context;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        context = Substitute.For<ITimeSheetContext>();
        countrybLL = new CountryBLLService(context);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(Exception),"Country Alreday exist")]
    public void CreateContry_throwEx()
    {
        countrybLL
            .When(x => x.CreateCountry(new Country()))
            .Do(x => { throw new Exception(); });

        countrybLL.CreateCountry(new Country());


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! NSubstitute will only work with instances you create using `Substitute.For<T>`. So you can use `When..Do`, `Returns`, `Received` etc with `context` (creating using NSubstitute), but not `countrybLL` (created using `new CountryBLLService`).

Try instead mocking via `context`:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(Exception),"Country Alreday exist")]
public void CreateContry_throwEx()
{
    var existingCountry = new Country();
    context.Countries
           .When(x => x.CreateCountry(existingCountry))
           .Do(x => { throw new Exception(); });
    // Or context.Contries.CreateCountry(...).Returns(...) for non-void member 

    countrybLL.CreateCountry(existingCountry);
}
```

---

As an aside, when I run into issues like this in my tests sometimes I find it useful to not use a mocking framework, and instead manually create a substitute for the dependency my class is using. This is what NSubstitute and other mocking libraries do for us automatically, but it can help to highlight exactly what I'm testing and what I'm faking for my test.

For example:

```
class CountryExistsRepository : ICountryRepository {
    public void CreateCountry(Country c) {
        throw new Exception("country already exists");
    }
    // ... other members omitted ...
}

[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(Exception),"Country already exist")]
public void CreateContry_throwEx()
{
    var existingCountry = new Country();

    var countrybLL = new CountryBLLService(
        new TimeSeetContext(new CountryExistsRepository()));

    countrybLL.CreateCountry(existingCountry);
}
```

I find this makes it clearer exactly what real code I'm using, compared with what I am faking for the test. Then once I get sick of manually implementing these cases then I switch to a mocking library to do it for me. In this case it shows that maybe we do not need to substitute for `TimeSeetContext`, only for the underlying `ICountryRepository`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Because my function Create is void, I had to use this implementation: context.Countries
                    .When(x => x.Create(Arg.Any<Country>()))
                    .Do(x => { throw new CountryException(); });

Comment: @BojanDelić I updated the example to use `When..Do` to better reflect this. :)